# getParentFragment() in fragments is returning null when fragment is popped out from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter, android-nested-fragment

I have an activity containg framelayout, fragment A is hosted with `getSupportFragmentManager()` in this.

This fragment A hosts two more fragments which has recycler views in it  -Fragment A1 and Fragment A2 using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. At this point of time i was  able to get Parent Fragment using `getSupportFragmentManager()` in Fragment A1 and A2.

Click on recycler view item in A1 and A2 results in another Fragment say Fragment B  that replaces  Fragment A and adds it to backstack.

Now the problem comes here, when i press back button i was able to get the Fragment State A view but  `getSupportFragmentManager()` is returning null for parent fragment in A1 and A2 fragments.

How should this method be used properly?

Comment: test getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager() please

Answer (score 1):

Use getChildFragmentManager() in viewpager when the viewpager is nested inside a fragment.

```
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```